# "How much is faster the train than the car?"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, comparatives

> 1. How much is faster the train than the car?
> 2. How much is the train faster than the car?

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much faster is a train than a car?

Comment: "How much faster is the train than the car?" If you're in America and change the articles from 'a' to 'the', then this answer gives the correct version of the original sentences, neither of which is correct. However, if here in the UK, then you'd use 'to' rather than 'than': "How much faster is the train to the car?"

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean "How much faster is the train than the car?" is correct when I'm in America ?

Comment: Yes, it does. "How much faster is the train than the car?" is correct in America. Technically speaking, 'than' is grammatically correct in the UK as well, but 'to' is also correct and the way people generally say it. In America, 'to' would never be used in this sentence, only 'than'.